# Pokémon Let's Go: What is the increased capture rate after capturing x amount of a certain Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

When I was chaining Caterpie the other day I noticed that the capture circle changed from yellow to green with a regular Pokéball. I was in a chain, but it was at an awkward number that wasn't close to a multiple of 10, and I didn't know if I did something special. Later I realized that I had hit 50 captures for Caterpie, and later on I tried it out with Geodude as well - the circle went from yellow to green with a Pokéball (though I checked after 100 captures this time).

My question comes in two parts.

First, assuming that there is a bonus for capturing x amount of a certain species, is it linear (as in every Pokémon captured grants a very small boost) or is it by interval (50, 100, 150, ...)?

Second, what are the actual numbers? Somewhere on a forum I read something about being able to get Chansey down to a green circle with a Pokéball, so assuming that this capture bonus exists, I'd like to know the hard numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent some time researching this, and have not been able to find hard numbers. My go-to source (serebii.net) only has this to say on the matter:

> As you increase your catches of the same species of Pokémon, the capture rate will increase. This does not have to be within a combo. [[Source]](https://serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/capture.shtml)

Various forum threads discuss bonuses at 50 and 100 total captures. Anecdotal evidence seems very strong for the bonus at 100 captures, and less strong for the bonus at 50 captures.

https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonLetsGo/comments/a0t40x/pokemon_becoming_easier_to_catch_not_tied_to/

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/240025-pokemon-lets-go-pikachu/77232663#9